# How to model a conditional probability without estimating joint PDF?

Tags: regression, probability, conditional-probability, nonlinear-regression, kernel-smoothing

I've around 3e3 two-dimensional data points,

```
   x,   d
1  1, 0.1
2  3, 0.1
3  2, 0.2
4  1, 0.5

range(x) = [-600, 600], range(d) = [0, 1]
```

We are trying to model `d` with a probability model. I believe the distribution of `d` should be dependent on `x`. So I'm up to model $Pr(d|x)$ rather than $Pr(d)$.

To do this, I am now using kernel density distribution to estimate the joint distribution of $Pr(d, x)$ and divide it by $Pr(x)$.

However, the number of data is enough to model $Pr(d)$ with kernel density estimation while insufficient to model $Pr(d,x)$.

So I'm wondering about this:

**Is there any model you suggest that can model `d` in a conditional way without modeling the joint distrubution?**

I have the following thoughts:

I can use SVM to deal with the short of data. However is there a way to train a "conditional SVM"?

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for **regression**. A wide definition of a regression model is *conditional modeling*, see [Definition and delimitation of regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173660/definition-and-delimitation-of-regression-model).  So to model the conditional expectation of $D \mid X$ you can use some kind of regression model, maybe a nonparametric one. You have not given sufficient details or context to say much more ... but for an example of copula regression, see [Conditional expectation of two identical marginal normal random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308775/conditional-expectation-of-two-identical-marginal-normal-random-variables/308831#308831).

You could simply start with a scatterplot smoother, such as lowess, or at least show us a plot of your data!