# Regression definition

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, definition

From Wikipedia:

> In statistical modeling, **regression** analysis is a statistical process
>   for estimating the relationships among variables. It includes many
>   techniques for modeling and analyzing several variables, when the
>   focus is on the relationship between a dependent variable and one or
>   more independent variables (or 'predictors').

Isn't the same for **classification**? In the end, isn't it the purpose of **machine learning**?

Comment: Related question: [Definition and delimitation of regression model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173660/definition-and-delimitation-of-regression-model)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Regression is far broader in purpose and scope than classification or machine learning** (however the latter might be understood).  There is, however, much overlap.

#### Relationships

Relationships analyzed by regression may consist of

- Association
- Dependence
- Causation

Classification provides information about the first two, but is silent about causation.  Both regression and machine learning have been used--sometimes successfully, often problematically--to draw conclusions about causation.

#### Purposes of Regression

1. To get a summary of multivariate data.
2. To set aside the effect of a variable that might confuse the issue.
3. Contribute to attempts at causal analysis.
4. Measure the size of an effect.
5. Try to discover a mathematical or empirical law.
6. Prediction.
7. Exclusion: getting $x$ "out of the way" when we want to study the relationship between two other variables that might be affected by $x$.

(After Mosteller & Tukey, *Data Analysis and Regression,* Chapter 12B.)

**Classification achieves almost none of these purposes.**  In limited ways it might provide some kind of summary (1) and help with discovery (5).

**Machine learning aims at prediction (6) almost exclusively.**  Most techniques of machine learning, ranging from random forests through neural networks to support vector models, are opaque to the understanding: they specifically do *not* aim to summarize data (1), remove the effects of confounding variables (2 and 7), or help us discover regularities that can be embodied in an empirical law (5).

---

This post is a slight expansion of an introductory presentation I made recently for a [semester course in regression.](http://www.quantdec.com/misc/MAT8406/)  Many more materials on the aims and practice of regression are available there.